# Fetch new data every 30 seconds using useQuery in React

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-query, tanstackreact-query

I am using '@tanstack/react-query' for fetching the data in my React + Typescript app.

Here is my sudo code, where I want to fetch metrics data every 30 seconds

```
  import { useQuery } from '@tanstack/react-query';
  import { subMinutes } from 'date-fns';

  const { data: metricData, isLoading } = useQuery({
    queryKey: ['fetch-metric', metricId],
    queryFn: () => {
       const startAt = subMinutes(new Date(), 10);
       const endAt = new Date();

      return getMetrics(metricId, {
        endAt: endAt.toISOString(),
        startAt: startAt.toISOString(),
      });
    },
    refetchOnWindowFocus: true,
    refetchInterval: 30000;
    },
  });
```

Here, I want to the keep metrics data locally in the memory which I receive from the API for the first time, and then I want to fetch only last 30 seconds of data next time onwards, also I want to remove the last 30 seconds of data from the value stored in the memory and append new 30 seconds of data which we receive from the API next time onwards.

How can I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if your API doesn't return full data sets, but only some `deltas`, you need to merge data yourself in the `queryFn`. Something like:

```
const { data: metricData, isLoading } = useQuery({
  queryKey: ['fetch-metric', metricId],
  queryFn: async ({ queryKey }) => {
    const startAt = subMinutes(new Date(), 10);
    const endAt = new Date();

    const oldData = queryClient.getQueryData(queryKey)

    const newData = await getMetrics(metricId, {
      endAt: endAt.toISOString(),
      startAt: startAt.toISOString(),
    });
    
    return mergeData(oldData, newData)
  },
  refetchOnWindowFocus: true,
  refetchInterval: 30000;
},
```

in `mergeData`, you would append the `newData` and potentially remove some things that you don't want to have in the cache anymore.